# Laravel gives me Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created one controller file as per below and routes for it. I want to display Hello World message on my website by entering this URL:
http://localhost/mylaravel/mycontroller but it shows me a 404 error.

Controller File:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function loadview()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () 
{
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('mycontroller','MyController@loadview');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your **web server is configured incorrectly** and Laravel application is not run. It's easy to check that, just add **die()** in **index.php** and see if you're still getting the 404 - if there is still the 404 error, then the request has not reached Laravel application.

Make sure **http://localhost/mylaravel** points to **public** folder of your Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not configured  `http://localhost/mylaravel` to point to the `public` folder in your project folder (`mylaravel`), then first try including `public` in the url: `http://localhost/mylaravel/public`

If the problem persists, you have to check if your server runs at all, and whether other sites on your `localhost` are fine. Go to `http://localhost/` in your browser to confirm. This should load an index page for your server. If `http://localhost/` returns `404` or some other error, then your server may be offline or needing attention.